# What is the essential supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I've encountered something called the "essential supremum" while working with $L^{p}$ spaces (in particular, for $p=\infty$).

I tried looking it up on the internet but all the definitions use concepts from Measure Theory, which I'm not familiar with. Is there a way to wrap my head around it *without having to deal with measures*? I really only need to understand this to show that a piecewise continuous function $f \in C(\Omega)$ is in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I can't seem to understand how the $L^\infty$ space works or how it is defined.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There isn't really, but if you're dealing with continuous functions and $L^p$ spaces you can at least hand-wave "measure" as "area/length" and probably be fine. Remember, we define

$$\operatorname{ess \, sup}(f) :=\inf \Big\{ a \in \mathbb{R} \, \Big| \, \mu \left( f^{-1}(a,\infty)\right)  = 0 \Big\}$$

In words: consider all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > a$. These often form intervals with positive length (measure). The essential supremum of $f$ is, loosely, the smallest $a$ for which the set of those $x$ has zero length (in the same sense as which the Cantor set has zero length).

Comment: You can perhaps somewhat naively replace essential supremum with ordinary supremum and be fine for all but the more strange functions you get when your focus is measurability. (In fact usually in my studies we just deal with suprema directly in the definition of, e.g., $L^\infty$. Perhaps not the best way to go about it, but you're not losing a ton and the intuition you have for suprema is probably significantly clearer.)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer So for example if I have the [hat function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), I could say that the essential supremum of the function is 1?

Comment: That is not possible, since the essential supremum of a measurable function $f$ is the "supremum" of $f$ up to ignoring the values of $f$ on a measure-zero set. (And of course, the notion of measure-zero set depends on the choice of the measure.) However, you always have $$\operatorname{ess}\sup(f)\leq\sup(f).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee Does this mean that if I want to show that my function is in $L^\infty$, I could just show that the supremum is finite?

Comment: $\sup|f|<\infty$ is a sufficient condition for a measurable function $f$ to be in $L^{\infty}$. This cannot be a necessary condition, though.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid specifying a measure when talking about $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ since the space depends critically on the measure you are using. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. The $L^{\infty}$ norm of a measurable function $f$ is defined as
$$\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\infty}} = \inf\{M \geq 0 : |f(x)| \leq M \text{ for $\mu$-almost every }x \in \Omega\}.$$
One can show that $|f(x)| \leq \lVert f \rVert_{L^{\infty}}$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in \Omega$, i.e. the $\inf$ is a actually minimum. $L^{\infty}(\Omega, \mu)$ is defined as the space of (equivalence classes of a.e. equal) measurable functions $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\infty}} < \infty$.
For your purpose, I guess you are using $\mu =$ Lebesgue measure, so that is the only measure you need to care about. To show that $\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\infty}} < \infty$, you need to show that there exists $M \geq 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for almost every $x \in \Omega$. So the procedure is very similar to the procedure for showing that $f$ is bounded, except here you are allowed exceptions on a set of measure $0$. Note that for continuous functions $f$ and $\mu$ a Borel measure (such as Lebesgue measure), if $\mu$ assigns positive measure to all open subsets of $\Omega$, then it can be shown that $\lVert f \rVert_{L^{\infty}} = \sup_{x \in \Omega}|f(x)|$. This is the case when $\Omega$ is open, or when $\Omega$ is an interval with more than one point.

Comment: FOr the final statement, one needs to impose certain conditions on $\Omega$, for example openness would be sufficient (it's probably implicit in the notation $C(\Omega)$ that $\Omega$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$, but I just wanted to be explicit, lest some future reader misinterprets).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks. For $f$ continuous, I need $S_M = \{x \in \Omega : |f(x)| > M\} \neq \emptyset$ to imply that $\mu(S_M) > 0$. So it is sufficient that $\mu$ assigns positive measure to all open subsets of $\Omega$.